# How to remove "%" displayed between words in answers generated by Open Trivia DB API?

Tags: javascript, api, text

I can't find an answer to this anywhere and there doesn't seem to be a solution on the API website. https://opentdb.com/api_config.php

I'm making a simple trivia quiz web app and my questions all display with%percent%sign%in%between%every%word%in%answer which obviously makes it very difficult to see the question.

How can I apply a fix to the text? [Link to github](https://github.com/arumbaua366/timedTriviaExplosion)

Comment: Are you sure it's `%` signs only? And not url-encoded data? If it's urlencoded data, in Javascript, you can easily use `decodeURIComponent` function to decode the data. `decodeURIComponent("Don%27t%20forget%20that%20%CF%80%20%3D%203.14%20%26%20doesn%27t%20equal%203.")`

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `replace()` ?

```js
var str = 'percent%sign%in%between%every%word%in%answer';
var str_final = str.replace(/%/g, ' ');

console.log(str_final);
```